# Centos 5.8 - firewall blocking Virtualizor staff

Tags: iptables, centos5, vnc

I run private KVM/OpenVZ hosting and im currently having issues with it. So I opened a ticket with virtualizor and they say they cant access the VNC connections, but I can. I figured the only thing blocking them would be Iptables, so I ran `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`, `iptables-save`.
They still say they can't connect I don't know what to do.

**Additional Info**

```
COMMAND: iptables -L -n -v -x

OUTPUT: 
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 372990 packets, 32637328 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 493 packets, 118009 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Ifconfig:

inet addr:198.204.xxx.xxx  Bcast:198.204.247.239  Mask:255.255.255.248
```

Comment: you need to give more information about your problem, One good starting point it could be describe what kind of virtualization you are using, kvm or openvz and show us iptables -vnL

Comment: KVM, the output is: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 13 packets, 624 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 3639 packets, 391K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23 packets, 3528 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: The default policy is accept... but there are rules to still block all traffic. Please look at your firewall rules (iptables -L -n -v -x) to see what rules there are, and what might be blocked.

Comment: If you want to allow all traffic, turn the firewall off (service iptables off, service ip6tables off). Putting the policy on accept won't work when there is a block-rule.

Comment: Also... is there a firewall or NAT box between your KVM host and the internet ? As in... is the IP of your box in a RFC1918 range (10.x.x.x, 172.16-31.x.x or 192.168.x.x)

Comment: it runs off a dedicated server hosted by datashack all the outputs are here I ran out of space when I pasted [link](http://pastebin.com/L95aVyVC)